# Connect MS Excel and/or MS Access with AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, yii, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have hired developers to make an app for me. The backend database is hosted on Amazon Web Service RDS. The server side language is PHP using Yii framework. originally when I awarded the work i asked the developers to make sure I could connect Excel and/or Access to the backend Database - AWS RDS in this case.

The developers are now telling me it is not possible to connect AWS RDS with MS Access. Instead they have asked me to install MYSQL workbench to connect with AWS RDS. That connection worked.

My question is: Is their statement true? is it not possible to use some sort of ODBC to allow MS Access to connect with AWS RDS. Can MS Access connect with AWS Dynamo DB? What if I switched to AWS hosted SQL Server?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

Should be no problem with current AWS - RDS technology

1. Set up 'instance' of your RDB. We used MySQL
2. Configure your VPC to talk, outbound and inbound. See AWS docs
   MySQL instance.
3. Install MySQL workbench to set up connection and try it out. See AWS docs

   a. Create a table in MySQL Workbench to make sure things work.

   b. Save the connection for reference, easy access and administration.
4. Install MySQL ODBC driver from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
5. Connect MS ACCESS to AWS hosted MySQL through ODBC driver

   - The Table created above in #3 should now be available
6. Finally

   a. Connect EXCEL to AWS hosted MySQL through ODBC driver. Under 'Data' tab select "From Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query -> [select] 'New Data Source'"

   b. Fill in the same parameters as above for "Create New Data Source" and your AWS data will flow right into your EXCEL spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, setup steps are below:

1. click Excel Data tab on the top
2. Get Data From--choose From Other Source--From ODBC
3. Data source name--choose Amazon Redshift ODBC DSN (If not show up, install AWS driver)
4. expand Advance option--Connection string type your "driver={Amazon
   Redshift (x64)};server.....
5. type in any SQL query--then click OK
6. type in aws workbench user name and password
7. a new sheet will be created with data
8. go to the table you want to paste the data, clear old data
9. click data tab, choose existing connection
10. paste query data to your desired excel cell
11. next time, just need to click Query Tab on the top, refresh

Answer (score 2):

Not positive about connecting to Amazon's RDS system. But I **do** know that you can setup MS Access to connect to MySQL. It's a bit finicky to setup to start with, but I've had a client running things successfully with a MySQL DB, Yii frontend and MS Access accessing the DB for backend work.

Works great. We're on a stock HostGator account and it's working fine for us. The main wrinkles have been working out how to speed up queries between MS Access and the MySQL DB, as you can quickly end up trying to access huge amounts of data that MS Access then joins **after** pulling it over the wire, rather than before.